# Array of Strings to functions and use strcpy

Tags: c

I have an array of `n` strings where `n` is not known at compilation time.

The real input is a giant string that I will splice, and add the parts to each position of the array.

In the example I've simulated a sentence with `n=3` , but `n` can be any number.

```
void addWords(char *array[][300], int n) {
    char p[] = "Hello ";
    char p1[] = "World ";
    char p2[] = "!";

    strcpy(array[0],p);
    strcpy(array[1],p1);
    strcpy(array[2],p2);

    printf("%s%s%s\n",array[0],array[1],array[2]);

}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n = 3;
    char array[n][300];

    addWords(array,3);

    return 0;
}
```

The code gives segmentation fault and I cannot identify the cause.

Comment: @BillLynch sorry, already edited main message, the error is segmentation fault

Comment: in `printf("%s%s%s\n",p[0],p[1],p[2]);` you're passing the wrong arguments to `printf`. `"%s"` format specifier expects a string, but you're passing a `char`.  Do you mean that to be `printf("%s%s%s\n",p0,p1,p2);`?

Comment: When compiled, your code produces numerous warnings that are fairly concerning. https://gist.github.com/sharth/b55c8a02f42a42a53c45a6863b5b6e05

Comment: @yano my bad, already fixed the code

Comment: Enable compiler warnings... and fix them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
//void addWords(char *array[][300], int n) {
void addWords(char array[][300], int n) { // <== use `char array[][300]`
    char p[] = "Hello ";
    char p1[] = "World ";
    char p2[] = "!";

    strcpy(array[0],p);
    strcpy(array[1],p1);
    strcpy(array[2],p2);

    //printf("%s%s%s\n",p[0],p[1],p[2]);
    printf("%s%s%s\n",array[0],array[1],array[2]); // <== I think you meant `array` instead of `p`
}
```

Comment: but I want to modify the array in the main, this only works on the function subspace, doesnt it? once the addWords is finished, the array is gone.

Comment: @digolira2 No, `char array[][300]` is already a pointer (because arrays decay to pointers), therefore when you modify `array[0]`, you're modifying the same array that is in `main`. It's just like using `char str[]` as a function parameter in order to modify a given string.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
void addWords(char *array[][300],
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

means

**pass a pointer to an array containing 300 char pointers**

What you want to say is

**pass a pointer to an array containing 300 char**

So all you need is:

```
void addWords(char *array[][300], --> void addWords(char array[][300],
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you declared 'addWords' with argument of type "char *array[][300]", but pass value of type "char array[n][300]". Different types.